Handling changes in user permissions across multiple layers (persona and company) in Sails.js
I am currently in the process of adding another layer of permissioning to our application - where it was previously handled by persona only, we are now allowing for company filtering too. So as an 'End-User' from 'Company A', I should only have access to the documents that are configured for that persona and company.
Mostly been fine, albeit a bit fiddly.
But I'm working on a beforeUpdate method within the Alert collection. This is responsible for broadcasting the relevant changes over socket connection.
Previously, the task involved identifying users who were added, removed, or persisted in access to the Alert, based solely on persona changes. However, with the introduction of the company layer, I now need to handle changes in both personas and companies to accurately determine added, removed, and persisted users.
To clarify, I need to translate these changes into three lists:

Added users
Removed users
Persisted users

This entails accounting for new personas, removed personas, and persisted personas, as well as new companies, removed companies, and persisted companies.Despite various attempts, I'm struggling to devise an efficient solution to handle these changes across both persona and company layers.
export const beforeUpdate = async (recordForUpdate, proceed): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const { id, visibleTo, companyVisibleTo } = recordForUpdate;
        const currentDate = new Date();


        const oldRecord = await Alert.get(id);

        const newPersonas = await Persona.getSlugsFromIds(recordForUpdate.visibleTo);
        const newCompanies = await Company.getCompanyNames([recordForUpdate]);

        let users: Array<string> = await getExternalUsers(
            externalSystemName,
            recordForUpdate,
            oldRecord
        );

        const {
            addedUsers,
            removedUsers,
            persistedUsers,
        } = await processUsers(
            users,
            newPersonas,
            oldPersonas,
            newCompanyNames,
            oldCompanyNames
        );

...
}


const processUsersWithPersonas = async (
    users: Array<string>,
    newPersonas: any,
    oldPersonas: any,
    newCompanies: Array<CompanyName>,
    oldCompanies: Array<CompanyName>
) => {
    const removedPersonas = _.difference(oldPersonas, newPersonas);
    const addedPersonas = _.difference(newPersonas, oldPersonas);
    const persistedPersonas = _.difference(newPersonas, [...addedPersonas, ...removedPersonas]);

    const removedCompanies = _.difference(oldCompanies, newCompanies);
    const addedCompanies = _.difference(newCompanies, oldCompanies);
    const persistedCompanies = _.difference(newCompanies, [...addedCompanies, ...removedCompanies]);


    const query: { [key: string]: any } = {
        isEnabled: true,
    };

    if (!_.isEmpty(users)) query.username = users;

    let addedUsers: Array<string> = [];
    let removedUsers: Array<string> = [];
    let persistedUsers: Array<string> = [];



